# find the integral using Integration by partial Fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

Here is my work for this problem...just wanted a check over and see if i missed anything
Original Problem: $\int$ $\frac6{x^3-3x^2}$

F 6/x^3-3x^2= F 6/x^2(x-3)

6/x^2(x-3)= Ax+B/x^2+C/(x-3)

C/x^2(x-3)= (A+C)x^2+(B-3A)x-3B

B=-2
A=-2/3
C=1/3

F C/x^2-3x^2 dx= F(-2/3)x-2/x^2+ F 2/3(x-3)

F -2/3x-2/x^2+2/3(x-3)

F 6/x^3-3x^2=-2/3 ln (x)+2/x+2/3 ln(x-3)

Comment: You're much more likely to get someone to look at this if you use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you would have used brackets for the denominators, then your result would be right. $\int \frac{6}{x^3-3x^3}\ dx=-2/3 \cdot ln(x)+2/x+2/3 \cdot ln(x-3)+C$

Answer (score 2):

We have the expansion

$$\frac{1}{x^3-3x^2}=\frac{A+Bx}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x-3}\tag 1$$

Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $x-3$ and letting $x\to 3$ reveals that $C=1/9$.

Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $x^2$ and letting $x\to 0$ reveals that $A=-1/3$.

Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $x^2$, taking a derivative with respect to $x$, and letting $x\to 0$ reveals that $B=-1/9$.

Thus, we have

$$\begin{align}\int\frac{6}{x^3-3x^2}\,dx&=\int\left(\frac{-2}{x^2}+\frac{-2/3}{x}+\frac{2/3}{x-3}\right)dx\\\\
&=\frac{2}{x}-\frac23\log |x|+\frac23 \log |x-3|+C
\end{align}$$